# Maintaining scroll position after postback (possible problem with AJAX Control Toolkit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have some problems with maintaining scroll position after postback. First time I experienced the problem was when I (believe) added Combobox control from AJAX control Toolkit and/or UpdatePanel from AJAX Extensions. The problem is when I do the postback on the page the page is loaded at the top and not where I did the postback.

Actually, this wouldn't be a problem if it isn't happening on a very large form.

I have already tried using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true", but it wasn't helpful at all.

I can provide the code if needed, but I don't think it would be of any use because I have comboboxes inside update panels which are rebinded on a button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using asp.net 4?  If so, there's a `Page.SetFocus(Control C)` method that should be what you're looking for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e04ah0f4.aspx

Note though, that according to the docs

> The SetFocus method will work only on
>   browsers supporting ECMAScript version
>   1.3 or later.

So it probably won't work with older versions of IE

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!